# If the table names are reversed in Left join will it result in Right join?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following situation . We have two tables users and orders. User table has three Columns Id,Name, Order_id . Orders table has two columns Id, and order_item.

> SQL query to get all the orders for each user.

```sql
 select * from users left join orders on users.order_id = orders.id;
```

> SQL Query to get all users for each order

```sql
 select * from users right join orders on users.order_id = orders.id;
```

> But I'm using Sqlite3 which currently does't not support Right, Full Outer join. So I tried following left join with inversed table names. which kinda solve my problem.

```sql
 select * from orders righ join users on users.order_id = orders.id;
```

So my question is if I reversed the tables name in left join will  it result in Right join ? Of course Right join has prints table columns in different order my query prints in different.

Please help me with this approach ? comparison with Real Right outer join , disadvantages and other notable things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RIGHT` joins are rarely used.
The reason is that a `LEFT` join is easier to perceive for  most people (my opinion, although maybe people that use RTL writing may disagree).

When you want **all** the rows of Table1 and **any** matching rows of Table2, usually you think about a resultset which at the left side of the results has the columns of Table1 and in the right side the columns of Table2.

So you write:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON <condition>
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON <condition>
```

> Of course Right join has prints table columns in different order my
> query prints in different

You must set explicitly the order of the columns in the results.
So instead of `SELECT *` if you want first the columns of Table2 write:

```
SELECT Table2.*, Table1.* ....
```

or if you don't want all the columns, enumerate all the columns that you want:

```
SELECT Table2.col1, Table2.col2, ...., Table1.col1, ....
```

Of course it's a good practice to use aliases to make the code shorter, so your query can be written:

```
SELECT o.*, u.* 
FROM orders AS o LEFT JOIN users AS u
ON u.order_id = o.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two tables, then yes.

With more tables, things get a little complicated.  The queries are not exactly the same, but they are under most circumstances.  The equivalent to:

```
from a left join b left join c
```

is:

```
from c right join (b right join a)
```

The issue is the order in which the `join`s are interpreted.  So the first version is:

```
from (a left join b) left join c
```

and this is subtly different from:

```
from a left join (b left join c)
```

depending on the conditions.